# how to use combineLatest with a Subscriber

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs6, rxjs-observables, rxjs-pipeable-operators

I want to use combineLatest with a subscriber and only subscribe through this method if only the id passed matches the itemIds.

Here is what i've done so far:

```
export interface Instance {
  onEvent<T = any>(eventName: string): Subscriber<T>;
}

export interface Payload {
  id: string;
  quantity: number;
}

public async getSingletonSubscription(id: string): Promise<Observable<any>>{
  const instance = await this.instance;
  // itemids is an Observable coming from another method. Just did an array for this example
  const itemIds: Array<number> = [1, 2];

  // Subscriber<any>
  const subscriber = instance.onEvent(message);

  const observable = combineLatest(
    subscriber,
    itemIds
  ).pipe(
    filter((payload: any, ids: any) => ids.include(id))
  );

  return observable
}
```

I'm currently getting a  type error of `Argument of type 'Subscriber<any>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ObservableInput<any> | SchedulerLike | ((...values: any[]) => unknown)'` and i'm currently not sure how I can get through this type error.

Normally I would use `interface.onEvent` this way

```
this.interface
  .onEvent(message)
  .subscribe((payload: Payload)) => console.log(payload));
```

but since itemIds would be an observable as well. I wanted to use combineLatest to subscribe once when I return an observable

Comment: What does `instance.onEvent(message)` return?

Comment: @JoshuaMcCarthy `onEvent<T = any>(eventName: string): Subscriber<T>`

Comment: @JoshuaMcCarthy updated to add more context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's quite a few misrepresentations in your code example, but I will try to explain each one.

Based on the following:

```
this.interface
  .onEvent(message)
  .subscribe((payload: Payload)) => console.log(payload));
```

The return type of `this.interface.onEvent()` is an `Observable`, not a `Subscriber`. A `Subscriber` is something that has an active `Subscription` to an `Observable`.

About your method, I would avoid mixing `Promises` and `Observables`. If you're working with RxJS, it is easier to make everything an `Observable`. Since `this.interface.onEvent(message)` returns an `Observable`, we can leave that as is.

Now for your updated code:

```
export interface Instance {
  onEvent<T>(eventName: string): Observable<T>;
}

export interface Payload {
  id: string;
  quantity: number;
}

public getSingletonObservable(id: string): Observable<Payload>{
  const instance$ = this.instance.onEvent<Payload>(message);
  // To make this an observable, we need to wrap it inside the `of()` operator.
  const itemIds$ = of([1, 2]);

  const observable$ = combineLatest([
    subscriber,
    itemIds
  ]).pipe(
    filter(([payload, ids]) => ids.include(payload.id)),
    // I'm assuming we want to return the payload if it passes the previous condition.
    map(([payload, ids]) => payload)
  );

  return observable$;
}
```

I updated the typing so we're not using `any` (which should be avoided at all cost in TypeScript).

I also updated some variable names, as it's common to add `$` to the end of a name if it's an observable.

You also forgot to declare where `id` is defined, so I added the reference that its a property of `payload`.

Answer (score -1):

Use `any` as return type of the function instead of Promise. Hopefully you'll get a solution.

Comment: The purpose of Typescript is to have a better understanding of what your code is doing. Using `any` to hide a type error is not a solution, it just makes the problem more abstract. https://img.devrant.com/devrant/rant/r_3015646_HZCi4.jpg